# Strategy in a waiting time game: fisherman's dilemma

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics

Suppose there is a fisherman out on the lake, who repeatedly casts his line looking for fish. Let $X_k$ denote the time it takes him to catch a fish on his $k$th cast, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, where the $X_k$ are iid, sampled from some distribution function $F$, and so that that $X_k > 0$ and $\mathbb{E}X < \infty$. The fisherman knows $F$, and has control over one thing: he can choose to re-cast his line at any time. What is his optimal strategy to catch the most fish in the long run?

There are situations where it is advantageous to re-cast: if $F$ is bi-modal, with the two modes very far apart, then the fisherman will wait for the first mode to pass, and if he hasn't caught a fish, re-cast the line rather than waiting to hit the next mode.

I can characterize the distribution functions where it is sometimes advantageous to re-cast via a direct computation, though I am curious if there is a more elegant condition. If the fisherman hasn't seen a fish up to time $t$, then his expected waiting time to see a fish is

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X - t | X > t] = \int_{t}^\infty \frac{F(s)}{F(t)} ds,
\end{equation}

where I'm using $F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X > x)$. On the other hand, the unconditional expected waiting time is

\begin{equation}
\mu = \mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^\infty F(s) ds.
\end{equation}

Thus, it is advantageous to re-cast our line at time $t$ if the conditional expected waiting time is larger than the unconditional waiting time, i.e. any time $t > 0$ satisfying

\begin{equation}
F(t) \int_0^\infty F(s) ds < \int_t^\infty F(s) ds.
\end{equation}

$\Big($**EDIT 2**: @DaneiWeissman pointed out that this condition isn't always the right one to figure out the optimal strategy. Assuming that the right strategy is to pick a time $t$ and always re-cast at that time, the waiting time for that strategy is

\begin{equation} \mathbb{E}[X|X \leq t] + \sum_{j \geq 0} F(t)^j(1-F(t)) jt = \frac{1}{1-F(t)} \int_0^t (F(s) - F(t)) ds + \frac{t F(t)}{1-F(t)} \end{equation}

\begin{equation} =\frac{1}{1-F(t)}\int_0^t F(s)ds.
\end{equation}

This is because we wait a geometrically-distributed number of times with failure probability $F(t)$ before there is a fish in $[0,t]$, and once this does occur, it takes time $\mathbb{E}[X|X \leq t]$ to catch it on average. So we should be instead be trying to solve

\begin{equation} \frac{1}{F(t)} \int_t^\infty F(s) ds = \frac{1}{1-F(t)} \int_0^t F(s) ds, \hspace{5pt} (\star \star)\end{equation}

or perhaps just minimize the RHS over $t \in \mathbb{R}$. $\Big)$

For example, if these expressions are equal for all $t$, then differentiating with respect to $t$ yields

\begin{equation}
\mu F'(t) = -F(t),
\end{equation}

and $F(t) = e^{-t/\mu}$ is the only distribution function on $[0,\infty)$ satisfying this ODE. So if the $X$'s are exponential then re-casting at any time never hurts or helps us. (*This shouldn't surprise anyone familiar with Poisson processes, and the memory-less property of the exponential distribution!*)

One can also compute directly with $F_\alpha(x) = (1+x)^{-\alpha}$, for $\alpha > 1$. This gives

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X - t | X > t] = \frac{t+1}{\alpha - 1},
\end{equation}

while

\begin{equation} \mathbb{E}X = \frac{1}{\alpha - 1}.
\end{equation}

So the fisherman should recast his line at *every positive time* in this case!

I am interested in the times $t$ where we have equality, namely times $t$ when

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X-t|X > t] = \mathbb{E}[X] \hspace{10pt} (\star)
\end{equation}

My questions are:

1) What possible sets can occur as solution sets to $(\star)$ or $(\star \star)$? For example, can there be a single unique solution? $N$ solutions for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$? Can it be satisfied for all $t$ in some interval?

2) Is there a nicer condition to determine whether or not there is *some* solution to $(\star$) or $(\star \star)$? (I wonder if there is some way to compare $F$ to an exponential distribution that would help.)

3) Can the integral equations $(\star)$ or $(\star \star)$ be reduced to a more tractable form?

4) Are there any other *nice* classes of distribution functions for which they can be solved explicitly?

**5) How would one make sense of the case where $\mathbb{E}X = \infty$? The equations $(\star)$ and $(\star \star)$ don't make sense anymore. Should the fisherman ever re-cast in this case?**

Also, I am curious if this question has been studied in any other context: it seems like a very natural setup to me!

P.S. There are many simple possible variants on the original question. I wonder what would happen if one imposed a time-cost on re-casting the line, or if the fisherman doesn't know how long has passed since he cast his line. What would the optimal strategy be?

**EDIT 1:** Another distribution one can prove something about is $F(t) = e^{-t^2}$, which decays *faster* than exponentially. We have $\mathbb{E}X = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$, while

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X-t | X > t] = e^{t^2} \int_{t}^\infty e^{-s^2} ds.
\end{equation}

It is straightforward to check that this function is strictly decreasing, and

\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to 0^+} \mathbb{E}[X-t | X > t] = \mathbb{E}X,
\end{equation}

which holds for any distribution function $F$ (since $F$ has right limits and $F(0) = 1$). Thus, in this case the fisherman should never recast his line.

Comment: What would be the expected waiting time for the distribution where the fisherman catches the fish at some time $t_0$ with probability $1/2$ and never otherwise?

Comment: @Peter That distribution has positive probability of being infinite, so of course the expected waiting time is infinite (any of the conditional expectations are also infinite for the same reason). The fisherman will obviously just wait until time $t_0$, and restart if he doesn't get a fish. Distributions with mass at infinity fall under the "what if $EX = \infty$" question -- it seems to me that there should still be an interesting strategy in this case.

Comment: This is a well known parameter in reliability engineering, called MTBF (mean time between fish).  OK, coudn't help myself there, they call it failure instead, and try to maximize it while you minimize, but the math is similar.

Comment: @MikeY cool! I was thinking about it, and it seems to me that the maximization and minimization problems are similar but not equivalent. I will look into it -- do you know of any treatments of MTBF from a theoretical perspective?

Comment: I believe there's a mistake in the conclusion for the example of $F(t) = e^{-t^2}$. In this case, the hazard function is strictly increasing, so I think the fisherman should *never* recast, rather than always recast as stated.

Comment: @DanielWeissman Thanks, the error has been fixed. I also had it backwards for the polynomially decaying distribution $F_\alpha$.

Comment: I don't think $\mathbb E[X−t|X>t]> \mathbb E[X]$ is the correct condition for wanting to recast. It's not necessary, because the fisherman has the option to re-cast a second time, e.g., if the hazard function $h(t)$ is given by $h(t<0.01)=2$, $h(0.01<t<100)=0$, $h(t>100)=1$, then at $t=100$ we have $\mathbb E[X−t|X>t]<\mathbb E[X]$, but the fisherman should still re-cast. It's not sufficient, because the fisherman could re-cast later, e.g., if $h$ is $h(t<100)=1$, $h(100<t<100.01)=2$, $h(t>100.01)=0.01$, then at $t=100$ we have $\mathbb E[X−t|X>t]>\mathbb E[X]$, but he shouldn't recast yet.

Comment: @DanielWeissman I'm not sure I understand your example. Why would that hazard function imply it's better to recast at t=100? (And how do you know that that hazard function actually occurs as the hazard function for some distribution F?)

Comment: @JRichey In the first case, he should always recast at any $t>0.01$. If he adopts the rule to always recast at $t=0.01$, he keeps the expected time between catches to $1/2$, which is optimal. Second question: you can construct $F$ from $h$: $F(t) = \exp[-\int_0^t dt' h(t')]$.

Comment: I think I see your point. It's wrong to compare the conditional expected waiting time to $\mathbb{E}[X|X>t]$ at $t=100$ in the first example, because we're not going to be waiting $\mathbb{E}X$: we're using this strategy where we re-cast repeatedly at $t=.01$, so we should be comparing to the expected time for that strategy.

Comment: This has some similarities to quantum Zeno's effect. If recasting/measurement resets the probability of event, we can change the probability it occurs after $t$ by frequent recasts. For example, if the probability to catch after $t$ is $\sin^2t/\tau$, you could recast every $T$ time units to get $\sin^{2t/T}T/\tau$ which approaches $0$ if you recast frequently enough. It is also related to how series of polarizers (like LCD) turn the polarization and absorbs almost nothing - the LCD lagers are the recasts and losing (absorbing) a photon would be the catch.

Comment: @JRichey $(\star\star)$ isn't quite correct: the term $tF(t)/(1-F(t))$ shouldn't be there. This is because $\mathbb E[X|X<t] \ne \int_0^t ds F(s)/(1-F(t))$. There is an extra term in the integration by parts because $F(t) \ne 0$, which exactly cancels the extra $tF(t)/(1-F(t))$. Even correcting this, I'm not sure that the equation is right. I think it would be better to just say that we're trying to find the value(s) of $t$ that minimize(s) $\int_0^t ds F(s)/(1-F(t))$.

Comment: @DanielWeissman You must be right, because the exponential distribution doesn't satisfy $(\star \star)$, which I think it should. But I don't know what you mean -- what integration by parts? I'm just using $\mathbb{P}(X > s | X < t) = \mathbb{P}(X>s) 1{s < t} / \mathbb{P}(X < t),$ so $\mathbb{E}[X | X < t] = \int_0^t \mathbb{P}(X >s)/\mathbb{P}(X < t) ds.$ I agree minimizing that yields the optimal strategy: this is indeed much simpler.

Comment: I was being silly: $\mathbb{P}(t > X > s) = F(s) - F(t)$, not $F(s) 1\{s < t\}$. This has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the probability density function, $t$ be the recast time and $T$ be the resulting average catch time. We have:
$$
\begin{align}
T &= \int_0^t x f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x + \left(\int_t^\infty f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x \right)(t + T) \\
T &= \frac{\displaystyle \int_0^t x f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x + t \int_t^\infty f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x}{\displaystyle 1 - \int_t^\infty f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x} \label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
The minimum is either at $t = 0$ (recast as soon as you can), $t = \infty$ (never recast), at $\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0$ or at a discontinuity of $f$. The case $t = \infty$ is simply the expected value. For $t = 0$ we take the limit to 0 and need to use L'Hôpital's rule.
$$
\lim_{t \downarrow 0}\ T = \lim_{t \downarrow 0}\ \frac{\displaystyle \int_t^\infty f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x}{f(t)} = \frac{1}{f(0)}
$$
Now the case $\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}T}{\mathrm{d}t} &= \frac{
 \left( \int_t^\infty f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x \right) \left( 1 - \int_t^\infty f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x \right)
 - \left( \int_0^t x f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x + t \int_t^\infty f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x \right) f(t)
}{
 \left( 1 - \int_t^\infty f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x \right)^2
} \\
0 &= \left( \int_t^\infty f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x \right) \left( 1 - t f(t) - \int_t^\infty f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x \right)
 - f(t) \int_0^t x f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$
Some examples:

- The exponential distribution $f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ has $T = \frac{1}{\lambda}$. It's the only distribution in which $T$ does not depend on $t$.
- In a delayed exponential distribution $t = \infty$ gives the minimum value for $T$.
  $$
    f(x) = \begin{cases}
      e^{1-x} & x \ge 1 \\
      0 & x < 1
    \end{cases}
    $$
- With the following distribution the minimum is at $t = 1$.
  $$
    f(x) = \begin{cases}
      \frac{1}{2} & x \in [0,1] \vee x \in [3,4] \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
    $$
- This distribution has minima at $t = 1$ and $t = \frac52$:
  $$
    f(x) = \begin{cases}
      \frac{1}{3} & x \in [0,1] \vee x \in [\frac32, \frac52] \vee x \in [5, 6] \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
    $$
- This gives a minimum at any $t \in [0, 1]$:
  $$
    f(x) = \begin{cases}
      e^{-x} & x \in [0,1] \\
      \frac{1}{e} & x \in [2,3] \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
    $$
- This gives a minimum at $t = 0$:
  $$
    f(x) = \begin{cases}
      e^{-x}-\frac{1}{e} & x \in [0,1] \\
      \frac{2}{e} & x \in [2,3] \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
    $$
- The following distribution has expected value $\infty$ and has a minimum at $t = 0$.
  $$
    f(x) = \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}
    $$

To your question if the fisherman should ever recast if the expected value of the distribution is $\infty$:
Yes, he should always do that. Recasting gives a finite value for $T$ while not recasting will give $T = \infty$.